# How can we find out if two colors are similar or not?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, linear-gradients

So I am trying to change the background of the text as well as the body. I am generating 4 different colors two of which are for the background gradient of the body whereas the other two are for the text.

I calculate a random HEX value using the following code:

```
  newbg1 = "#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
  newbg2 = "#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
  newbgtext1 = "#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
  newbgtext2 = "#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
```

(I apologize for the lack of sensible variable names here)

After this, I perform the following checks to make sure that these are indeed complete 6-digit HEX codes with a "#" preceding them.

```
if(newbg1.length<7 || newbg2.length<7||newbgtext1.length<7||newbgtext2.length<7)
    onclick();
```

If any of the generated codes are not of these lengths I call the function itself to generate new hex codes.

However, this is where I encounter a problem. Although the codes are randomly generated, many times it looked like the gradient doesn't exist and it is a solid color. 
I assumed it is because the same colors are being selected (highly unlikely, but not impossible).

Thus I added another if-statement to check if the colors are the same or not.

```
if(newbg1 == newbg2 || newbgtext2==newbgtext1 || newbg1 == newbgtext1 || newbg1 == newbgtext2 || newbg2 += newbgtext1 || newbg2 == newbgtext2)
     onclick();
```

But this still fails to resolve the issue. After a bit trail and error I arrived at the conclusion that the colors are *similar* and not the *same*.

I need a method of identifying if 2 given hex values are similar to each other or not and by what degree are they similar. I would also like to know what the minimum difference of 2 hex colors must be so as to obtain a discernable gradient.

I shall also add the complete JS code below:

```
var bg = document.getElementById("bg");
var inv = document.getElementById("inv");
var textbg = document.getElementById("textbg");

inv.style.opacity="0";
document.body.addEventListener("click", onclick);

function onclick() {
  newbg1 = "#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
  newbg2 = "#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
  newbgtext1 = "#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
  newbgtext2 = "#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);

  if(newbg1.length<7 || newbg2.length<7||newbgtext1.length<7||newbgtext2.length<7)
    onclick();
  if(newbg1 == newbg2 || newbgtext2==newbgtext1 || newbg1 == newbgtext1 || newbg1 == newbgtext2 || newbg2 == newbgtext1 || newbg2 == newbgtext2)
    onclick();

  inv.style.opacity="1";
  setTimeout(function() {
    bg.style.background = "linear-gradient(-45deg," + newbg1 +"," + newbg2 + ")";
    inv.style.opacity="0";
    bg.style.backgroundSize = "200% 200%";
    bg.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    textbg.style.background = "linear-gradient(-45deg," + newbgtext1 +"," + newbgtext2 + "," + newbgtext1 + ")";
    textbg.style.backgroundSize = "200% 200%";
    textbg.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    textbg.style.webkitBackgroundClip = "text";
    textbg.style.webkitTextFillColor= "transparent";
  }, 500);

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exists out there already to help you solve this problem but since "similar" is very relative it's quite possible you'll have to make a custom function. You need to decide how close in value a hex can be to another to count as "similar" and then do that check. If it were me I'd probably break the hex into three hexes representing each color and then test from there.

Comment: @Ashley Okay I shall work that and let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: why not check the difference between the hex numbers and make sure the smallest difference is greater than X

Comment: @DCR what you are suggesting is correct. But the question is how much difference in the hex values will produce a discernable gradient?

Comment: kinda in the eye of the beholder.  Try some and go with what works for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, You should use `.padStart` function, for the case the given number as small (to fill it with leading zeros). like this:

```
 newbg1 = "#"  + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16).padStart(6, '0');
```

About check for similarity - You can get the `RGB` of the colors, and calculate the total distance between each. if it's bigger then some defined value - it's not similar. otherwise - it's similar.

Something like this:

(in the following example the total color change to be colled different is 50, but play with it)

```js
function getRGB(color) {
  color = parseInt(color.substring(1), 16);
  r = color >> 16;
  g = (color - (r<<16)) >> 8;
  b = color - (r<<16) - (g<<8);
  return [r, g, b];
}
function isSimilar([r1, g1, b1], [r2, g2, b2]) {
  return Math.abs(r1-r2)+Math.abs(g1-g2)+Math.abs(b1-b2) < 50;
}

console.log(isSimilar(getRGB('#ffffff'), getRGB('#000000'))) // white and black
console.log(isSimilar(getRGB('#f10103'), getRGB('#fa1012'))) // to kinds of red
```

Comment: Worked like a magic !!